# Worker Group VS Node Group EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud, terraform, amazon-eks

I am trying to use https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/12.2.0(Terraform AWS EKS provider)

What is the difference between worker nodes and node group?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that `node_groups` are Amazon EKS managed nodes and `worker_groups` are self managed nodes.

Check this Github [issue](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/895) for more details.